# Modal pop-up not working properly (want the background page to dim)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

There's a button overlayed on a page, and once the button is pressed, the page is supposed to be dimmed and a modal popup shows up.

However, for my code, the popup just shows up but the background page isn't affected whatsoever. The modal opens and closes correctly, however.

Code for the button:

```
class MessageBrokerButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isShowing: false
        }
    }

    openModalHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            isShowing: true
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    closeModalHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            isShowing: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className='message-broker' onClick={this.openModalHandler}>
                    Message Broker
                </button>
                <div className='message-icon'></div>

                { this.state.isShowing ?         
                    <Popup 
                        show={this.state.isShowing} 
                        close={this.closeModalHandler}>
                            Test
                    </Popup> 
                    : null 
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Code for the modal:

```
const Popup = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.close}>CLOSE</button>
            <p> {props.children}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Relevant code for the page the button is on:

```
class Page extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    };

    render() {
        let page100 = 
        <div>
            <MessageBrokerButton></MessageBrokerButton>
        </div>

        if (this.props.currentPage !== this.state.page) {
            page100 = null;
        }

        return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

            {page100}

        </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I know I'm definitely not taking into consideration the right styling rules, and also what to do about altering the Page class once the MessageBrokerButton is clicked. But I'm not exactly sure which parts to change and what I should be changing.

Comment: probably want an overlay element that has a `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` or something to do the page dimming. That would probably be fixed position as a full screen element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. What you could do is create a new Shadow-component that is a child of Page (or whatever is your actual root component). This Shadow is then given a state prop that tells the component whether to render the shadow-div or not.

All this is pretty easy. The most complex part is usually to come up with some sensible state management system so that you can trigger the Shadow without passing the "enable shadow" handler all around. I suggest to check out Redux for this.

Use z-index style to make sure the shadow appears between the Page and the modal. For Example shadow z-index 1, modal container 2. Also, make sure both shadow and the modal container are positioned as absolute as they both should overlay the page.

Here's a pseudo-simplification:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasShadow: false,
      modal: null, // Modal can be a React-component, like the Popup.
    };
  }
  handleHasShadow = hasShadow => {
    this.setState({ hasShadow });
  }
  handleSetModal = modal => {
    this.setState({ modal });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form ...>
          {
            this.props.currentPage === this.state.page
              ? <MessageBrokerButton handleHasShadow={this.handleHasShadow} />
              : null
          }
        </form>
        <Shadow isEnabled={this.state.hasShadow} />
        {/* You can give modal as a prop too! */}
        <ModalContainer>{modal}</ModalContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Shadow.jsx

```
const Shadow = ({ isEnabled }) => {
  return isEnabled ? (
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        background: '#000000',
        opacity: 0.5,
        zIndex: 1,
      }}
    />
  ) : null;
}
```

Now you just use the this.props.handleHasShadow(true/false) function to enable/disable the shadow. The shadow will be as big as the parent (Page) component.

You may also want to make sure that the focus stays inside your modal. Otherwise users will be able to tab-out from the modal. Keyword here is focus-trap.

Comment: It's correctly passing around the props and triggering the Shadow (I console logged to make sure), but I think something about the styling might be off? It's just a blank white page that covers the whole page (even if I change the background-color), in the console the body has no HTML.

Comment: Does the browser's inspector console have any error messages? It sounds like the browser failed to render the site. Make sure your syntax is intact, don't directly copy the pseudo-code.

Comment: Got it, I wasn't doing the in-line styling right. Do you know why my z-indexing isn't working? The shadow appears at the top of the stack, even over the modal. I set the modal as 2, shadow as 1, and page as 0. Not sure if it's because since the Page component renders both the Shadow and the Button which triggers the Popup if clicked, something about the inheriting is off?

Comment: Hey, make sure your modal container that holds the pop-up modal is positioned as "absolute" too. I'll update the answer.